# Whitespaces aren't being trimmed Golang templates

Tags: html, go-templates

In the following code, the white spaces aren't being trimmed despite using {{--}}

```
{{$first := true}}
{{range $name, $value := .Labels}}
  {{if $first}}
    {{$first = false}}
  {{else}}
    ,
  {{end}}
    {{$name}}={{$value -}}
{{end}}
```

So it prints like this: name=value , name2=value2

I'm not sure why the whitespaces aren't being trimmed... .Labels is a map[string]string
and the strings don't have spaces in them, since the following:

```
{{range $name, $value := .Labels}}
  {{$name}}={{$value}},
{{end}}
```

prints without the leading space like this: name=value, name2=value2,

Comment: The second prints without the leading space because there's no leading space in the template. Templates condense consecutive whitespace into a single space character (which is also how HTML renders).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{ $first := true -}}
{{ range $name, $value := .Labels -}}
    {{ if $first -}}
        {{ $first = false -}}
    {{ else -}}
        {{- ", " -}}
    {{ end -}}
    
    {{ $name }}={{ $value -}}
{{ end }}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/0r69PUj3mEi